# Make an batch file that runs commando in WinPython Command Prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, python-3.x

How do I write an batch file that will execute a commando "python my_program.py" from the WinPython Command Prompt? Not from the cmd.exe!

Comment: 1. What is the WinPython command prompt? 2. Do you mean PythonWin? 3. What does the prompt look like?

Comment: You find it here: http://winpython.sourceforge.net/

Comment: There are several command prompts listed. Do you mean the "WinPython Command Prompt" in the picture at http://winpython.github.io/ in the Overview section?

Comment: Yes, that' the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by removing the path from normal python installation. I also uninstalled the normal python distribution. I also made a path to the python version in WinPython. Now I can use the normal cmd to run the program. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Have a try:

In the section ["Portable or not, the choice is yours!"](http://winpython.github.io/) it describes how to " register your distribution to Windows".
When you register WinPython in Windows you can double-click the files and the execute. This also means that you can run the file just by typing the name of the file in the command prompt (cmd.exe and other) as `my_program.py`. Note: On linux systems you would write for instance `python my_program.py` to tell python to run this program. In contrast, on Windows, once you registered your extension you can run it without telling windows which interpreter to use.

If you want to use a specific interpreter for `my_program.py`, you need to specify the path of the interpreter.
I installed WinPython at `C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3`,
so my command is `C:\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\scripts\python.bat my_program.py`.
I also installed Python 3 so my path to python.exe is `C:\Python34\python.exe`
and my command is `C:\Python34\python.exe my_program.py`.

Try it out and tell me if it does not work.

Comment: Good try, but it doesn't find all the lib-packages when I try to run the code. my_program.py must be run in the WinPython Command Prompt to run.

Comment: Can you describe the exact steps you take and the output you get and the output you expect in your question?

Answer (score 0):

The reply is late, but could help others.

You could use the `env_for_icons.bat` Under Winpython installation folder.

It can be used in your bat file as follows:

```
@echo off
call "WinPythonPath\scripts\env_for_icons.bat" 
REM cmd.exe /c jupyter nbconvert --execute *.ipynb --no-input --no-prompt --to html
REM Or in your specific case
cmd.exe /c python my_program.py
exit
```